# How could I make a reusable confirmation control using Bootstrap Modals and buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am trying to make it possible for a user to confirm something by opening Bootstrap modals as well as using these same modals for different features. In this question I will be using a "calculator" sort of element as an example for an additional feature. As it stands now, the confirmations won't work unless I add JQuery's `$target.off();` to `targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {});`.

When I add this piece of JQuery code, it will cause any other features I use (regarding Bootstrap modals) on this page to break as well, meaning I would require to add additional code for any of those features. I would not desire for that to happen. How could I make these confirmations work properly whilst keeping other features work fine without adding additional code for these features?

What should happen:

1. When "No" is selected, the button (for "no" obviously) should stay the same color, however the opposite button (the "yes" button) should turn grey-ish and the "Confirm?" button should turn disabled (if not already). Also if a `<button class="btn btn-warning pending">Pending</button>` is visible, this should be hidden.
2. When "Yes" is selected, the button (for "yes") should stay the same color, however the opposite button (the "no" button) should turn grey-ish and the "Confirm?" button should turn enabled.
3. When the "Confirm?" button is clicked, it should populate a modal with anything related to a confirmation and open up given modal.
4. When the modal has been exited out/closed **during** the confirmation **without** completing the confirmation, function `WillClose()` (which in turn should change the pending button text of given confirmation control to "try again") should be executed.
5. When a confirmation has successfuly been executed (by clicking a "confirm" button inside given modal), the modal should hide/disappear (and reset the content inside) and execute `ConfirmModal()` function (which in turn should disable all buttons for given confirmation control and change the pending button text to "Confirmed").
6. Any of these confirmations should work independently from one another.

What is happening:

The confirmation elements trigger one another's pending buttons, unless I add `$target.off()` to the modal (e.g. `targetModal.off()`). Doing the latter however, will cause other features to "break". What I mean by this, is that whatever will be "populated", "inserted" or "cloned" (whatever you want to call this) inside a modal, it will be placed inside the modal multiple times (as if the modal does not reset, makes sense?).

How could I make the following work?

```js
//Fields:

//Yes selector
const positiveSelector = ".positive";
//No selector
const negativeSelector = ".negative";
//Confirm? selector
const confirmSelector = ".init-confirm";
//Pending selector
const pendingSelector = ".pending";
//calTrigger selector
const calcTriggerSelector = ".calc-trigger > button";
//Yes elements
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector);
//No elements
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector);
//Confirm? elements
const confirmNodes = document.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector);
//Pending elements
const pendingNodes = document.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector);
//calcTrigger elements
const calcTriggerNodes = document.querySelectorAll(calcTriggerSelector);

//Modal
const targetModalSelector = "#bs-modal-xl";
const targetModal = $(targetModalSelector);
const $modalInit = targetModal.html();

//Eventlisteners:

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  EnableConfirmBtn(this);
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  DisableConfirmBtn(this);
}));

confirmNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  OpenConfirmModal(this);
}));

calcTriggerNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", calcTrigger));

//Reset modal when closing
targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  targetModal.html($modalInit);
});

//Methods:

function EnableConfirmBtn(ele) {
  ele.classList.add("btn-success");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.removeAttribute("disabled"));
}

function DisableConfirmBtn(ele) {
  ele.classList.add("btn-warning");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
  ele.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
}

function OpenConfirmModal(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "inline-block");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-danger"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Pending");

  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-body").html($(".clone-one").clone());
  $(targetModalSelector + " .clone-one").show();
  $(targetModalSelector + " h4.modal-title").text("");
  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  targetModal.modal();

  targetModal.on("click", ".clone-one", function () {
    targetModal.modal("hide");
    ConfirmModal(ele);
  });

  targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    WillClose(ele);
    //Make use of targetModal.off(); here? <--
    //targetModal.off();
    targetModal.html($modalInit);
  });
}

function ConfirmModal(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Confirmed");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-danger", "btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-success"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "none");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".btn-group > button").forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
}

function WillClose(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Try again");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-danger"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-warning"));
}

function calcTrigger() {
  ModalHandler($(".calc").clone(), "", "", true, true);
  $(targetModalSelector + " .calc").show();
  targetModal.modal();

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-one-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "1");
  }));

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-two-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "2");
  }));

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-three-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "3");
  }));
  
  //I would not want to be using something like this:

  //Reset modal when closing
  //targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  //targetModal.off();
  //targetModal.html($modalInit);
  //});
}

//Modal handling (not required when not using Modal):
function ModalHandler(content, title, footer = "", bigCloseBtn = false, emptyFooter = false) {
  $(targetModalSelector + " h4.modal-title").text(title);
  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-body").html(content);

  if (footer != "" && footer != undefined) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-footer").html(footer);
  }

  if (bigCloseBtn) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").css("float", "right");
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").addClass("btn btn-lg btn-danger");
    //$(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").html("close");
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").removeClass("close");
  }

  if (emptyFooter) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  }
}
```

```css
#foo-container {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .pending {
    display: none;
  }

  .clone-one, .calc {
    display: none;
  }

  .calc {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .calc button, .calc .result-container {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }

  .calc [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="calc" class="calc">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="result-container">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="x" id="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="1" id="number-one-btn">
          1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="2" id="number-two-btn">
          2
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="3" id="number-three-btn">
          3
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="" id="number-one-btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="foo-container">
    <div class="confirmation-box">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="confirmation-box">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="calc-trigger">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
        Calc trigger
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clone-one">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jd3m1bt/)

I am merely looking for a solution that requires minimal code as possible. If given example can be rewritten to be smaller, please let me know.

**Edit:** I am aware that the code provided above adds multiple event listeners the more I click on certain controls causing problems. So that is why I am looking for a (simple as possible) solution to make all these controls work independently whilst keeping the script unobtrusive as well as to keep as much of the formatting of the code provided above.

Answer (score 4):

The problem *right now*: when you use

```js
targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
  WillClose(ele);
  //Make use of targetModal.off(); here? <--
  //targetModal.off();
  targetModal.html($modalInit);
});
```

inside the `OpenConfirmModal` function a new event handler is attached every time you open the dialog. This leads to the following situation:

1. Dialog is opened and event handler is attached.
2. Dialog is closed and one event handler is executed.
3. Dialog is opened and *another* event handler is attached.
4. Dialog is closed and two event handlers are executed.
5. Dialog is opened and *another* event handler is attached.
6. Dialog is closed and three event handlers are executed.

And so on. There is a similar issue with confirmation, too. I've modified the code to just add a console log to demonstrate this - opening and closing makes more and more logs to the console:

```js
//Fields:

//Yes selector
const positiveSelector = ".positive";
//No selector
const negativeSelector = ".negative";
//Confirm? selector
const confirmSelector = ".init-confirm";
//Pending selector
const pendingSelector = ".pending";
//calTrigger selector
const calcTriggerSelector = ".calc-trigger > button";
//Yes elements
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector);
//No elements
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector);
//Confirm? elements
const confirmNodes = document.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector);
//Pending elements
const pendingNodes = document.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector);
//calcTrigger elements
const calcTriggerNodes = document.querySelectorAll(calcTriggerSelector);

//Modal
const targetModalSelector = "#bs-modal-xl";
const targetModal = $(targetModalSelector);
const $modalInit = targetModal.html();

//Eventlisteners:

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  EnableConfirmBtn(this);
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  DisableConfirmBtn(this);
}));

confirmNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  OpenConfirmModal(this);
}));

calcTriggerNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", calcTrigger));

//Reset modal when closing
targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  targetModal.html($modalInit);
});

//Methods:

function EnableConfirmBtn(ele) {
  ele.classList.add("btn-success");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.removeAttribute("disabled"));
}

function DisableConfirmBtn(ele) {
  ele.classList.add("btn-warning");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
  ele.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
}

function OpenConfirmModal(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "inline-block");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-danger"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Pending");

  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-body").html($(".clone-one").clone());
  $(targetModalSelector + " .clone-one").show();
  $(targetModalSelector + " h4.modal-title").text("");
  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  targetModal.modal();

  targetModal.on("click", ".clone-one", function () {
    targetModal.modal("hide");
    console.log("hiding")
    ConfirmModal(ele);
  });

  targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    WillClose(ele);
    console.log("closing");
    //Make use of targetModal.off(); here? <--
    //targetModal.off();
    targetModal.html($modalInit);
  });
}

function ConfirmModal(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Confirmed");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-danger", "btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-success"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "none");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".btn-group > button").forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
}

function WillClose(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Try again");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-danger"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-warning"));
}

function calcTrigger() {
  ModalHandler($(".calc").clone(), "", "", true, true);
  $(targetModalSelector + " .calc").show();
  targetModal.modal();

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-one-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "1");
  }));

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-two-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "2");
  }));

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-three-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "3");
  }));
  
  //I would not want to be using something like this:

  //Reset modal when closing
  //targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  //targetModal.off();
  //targetModal.html($modalInit);
  //});
}

//Modal handling (not required when not using Modal):
function ModalHandler(content, title, footer = "", bigCloseBtn = false, emptyFooter = false) {
  $(targetModalSelector + " h4.modal-title").text(title);
  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-body").html(content);

  if (footer != "" && footer != undefined) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-footer").html(footer);
  }

  if (bigCloseBtn) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").css("float", "right");
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").addClass("btn btn-lg btn-danger");
    //$(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").html("close");
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").removeClass("close");
  }

  if (emptyFooter) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  }
}
```

```css
#foo-container {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .pending {
    display: none;
  }

  .clone-one, .calc {
    display: none;
  }

  .calc {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .calc button, .calc .result-container {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }

  .calc [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="calc" class="calc">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="result-container">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="x" id="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="1" id="number-one-btn">
          1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="2" id="number-two-btn">
          2
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="3" id="number-three-btn">
          3
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="" id="number-one-btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="foo-container">
    <div class="confirmation-box">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="confirmation-box">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="calc-trigger">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
        Calc trigger
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clone-one">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You *can* use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to avoid that, however it's not the best idea as it actually makes the code more awkward.

- when calling `.off` you can just specify an event, however, this will remove *all* handlers for that event. `targetModal.off("hidden.bs.modal");` will work for a simple case but you might add a second handler from elsewhere that works correctly (it doesn't get continually re-added) and that will also be wiped out.
- if you call `.off` with a specific handler to remove, you need a reference to the handler. This is more useful but even more awkward - your code would *effectively* look like this:

```js
var handler = function (e) {
//  ^^^^^^^------------------------------------------------------------------ <-   
  WillClose(ele);                                  //                          |
  targetModal.off("hidden.bs.modal", "*" handler); // `handler` references -> -^
//                                    ^--------------
  targetModal.html($modalInit);//                   |  these need to match because 
}//                                                 |  .off() requires a second parameter
//                                                  |  parameter to use the handler ref
targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", "*", handler);//  |  this mandates that .on() also
//                                 ^ ----------------  uses the second parmeter
```

Instead, use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which is a combination of `.on` with an implicit `.off` - it will attach the callback function as event handler and then remove it after it executes once. This way you don't have to call `.off` yourself.

Here is your code that utilises `.one` - now if you open and close the dialog repeatedly, you'd only get a single log in the console, instead n+1 based on the number of times you've opened the dialog:

```js
//Fields:

//Yes selector
const positiveSelector = ".positive";
//No selector
const negativeSelector = ".negative";
//Confirm? selector
const confirmSelector = ".init-confirm";
//Pending selector
const pendingSelector = ".pending";
//calTrigger selector
const calcTriggerSelector = ".calc-trigger > button";
//Yes elements
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector);
//No elements
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector);
//Confirm? elements
const confirmNodes = document.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector);
//Pending elements
const pendingNodes = document.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector);
//calcTrigger elements
const calcTriggerNodes = document.querySelectorAll(calcTriggerSelector);

//Modal
const targetModalSelector = "#bs-modal-xl";
const targetModal = $(targetModalSelector);
const $modalInit = targetModal.html();

//Eventlisteners:

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  EnableConfirmBtn(this);
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  DisableConfirmBtn(this);
}));

confirmNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
  OpenConfirmModal(this);
}));

calcTriggerNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", calcTrigger));

//Reset modal when closing
targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  targetModal.html($modalInit);
});

//Methods:

function EnableConfirmBtn(ele) {
  ele.classList.add("btn-success");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(negativeSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.removeAttribute("disabled"));
}

function DisableConfirmBtn(ele) {
  ele.classList.add("btn-warning");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(positiveSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
  ele.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
}

function OpenConfirmModal(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "inline-block");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-danger"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Pending");

  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-body").html($(".clone-one").clone());
  $(targetModalSelector + " .clone-one").show();
  $(targetModalSelector + " h4.modal-title").text("");
  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  targetModal.modal();
  
  targetModal.one("click", ".clone-one", function () {
  //one --------^
    targetModal.modal("hide");
    console.log("hide")
    ConfirmModal(ele);
  });

  targetModal.one("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
  //one --------^
    WillClose(ele);
    console.log("will close")
    targetModal.html($modalInit);
  });
}

function ConfirmModal(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Confirmed");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-danger", "btn-warning"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-success"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(confirmSelector).forEach(node => node.style.display = "none");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".btn-group > button").forEach(node => node.setAttribute("disabled", ""));
}

function WillClose(ele) {
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.textContent = "Try again");
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-danger"));
  ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector).forEach(node => node.classList.add("btn-warning"));
}

function calcTrigger() {
  ModalHandler($(".calc").clone(), "", "", true, true);
  $(targetModalSelector + " .calc").show();
  targetModal.modal();

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-one-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "1");
  }));

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-two-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "2");
  }));

  document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc #number-three-btn").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(targetModalSelector + " .calc .result-container input").forEach(node => node.value += "3");
  }));
  
  //I would not want to be using something like this:

  //Reset modal when closing
  //targetModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  //targetModal.off();
  //targetModal.html($modalInit);
  //});
}

//Modal handling (not required when not using Modal):
function ModalHandler(content, title, footer = "", bigCloseBtn = false, emptyFooter = false) {
  $(targetModalSelector + " h4.modal-title").text(title);
  $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-body").html(content);

  if (footer != "" && footer != undefined) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-footer").html(footer);
  }

  if (bigCloseBtn) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").css("float", "right");
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").addClass("btn btn-lg btn-danger");
    //$(".modal .modal-content .modal-header button.close").html("close");
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-header button.close").removeClass("close");
  }

  if (emptyFooter) {
    $(targetModalSelector + " .modal-content .modal-footer").html("");
  }
}
```

```css
#foo-container {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .pending {
    display: none;
  }

  .clone-one, .calc {
    display: none;
  }

  .calc {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .calc button, .calc .result-container {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }

  .calc [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="calc" class="calc">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="result-container">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="x" id="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="1" id="number-one-btn">
          1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="2" id="number-two-btn">
          2
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="3" id="number-three-btn">
          3
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="" id="number-one-btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="foo-container">
    <div class="confirmation-box">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="confirmation-box">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success positive">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning negative">No</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger init-confirm" disabled>Confirm?</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pending" disabled>Pending</button>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="calc-trigger">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
        Calc trigger
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clone-one">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But why does it change the first pending button text from "try again" to confirmed when confirming any confirmation but first? I feel like I still need to add some code to keep these separated: [Step 1](https://i.imgur.com/JOiIWo0.png) -> [Step 2](https://i.imgur.com/yEJ7sAl.png) -> [Step 3](https://i.imgur.com/3dbXYSF.png)

Comment: @Barrosy because you do `ele.parentNode.querySelectorAll(pendingSelector)` and that catches all of the buttons. You need to have some way of disqualifying the button that's not needed right now.

Comment: I tried that by using the clicked element (a.k.a. `this`) and then look for its parent container and within that container find the pending button. So why is it getting a pending button from a "different parent container" in the code above?

Comment: @Barrosy ah, ffs I remembered now. There is another problem that the handler would be attached but if it's not executed would stay. I've seen this once and I didn't realise it until now. What happens is that you open -> attach with `.one` for *confirmation*  -> close without confirming, so handler stays -> open the dialog -> attach another handler with `.one` -> if you hit "Confirm", now both would be executed.

Comment: @Barrosy ugh, unfortunately I don't have time right now and I'll probably be back on Monday the earliest to have a look at this. I have to re-engineer my previous solution here, since I can't remember what it was. The issue is as I described above - you'd get event handlers attached but not fired, so even though they'd execute *once*, they hang around and you'd get multiple handlers each executing once and destroying themselves. I can't remember what I did but you have to manage the handlers and remove them if they don't fire. Maybe this would help you find a solution before I come back.

Comment: Yes I am trying whatever I could do to solve this problem but I seem to have a rather difficult time even with the help you provided. Everything I try to solve this problem, causes another problem to rise. It looks like a simple confirmation and yet it's strangely very hard to get it work bug free. For some reason the code sets the `ele` parameter defined within `OpenConfirmModal` to the confirmation previous clicked confirmation button and I really do not get why this is happening, but I will try to tinker around and see if I can find anything in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Barrosy it *looks* simple but the problem is that the same dialog is re-used, so any handlers you attach will remain. When you close the dialog without confirming, then the confirmation handler is still there when you open again. So, the dialog starts accruing more and more stuff any time you open it, instead of having a simple state that is reset every time.